# Maven dependency for jira-rest-java-client-0.2-m1.jar

Tags: maven, jira, jira-rest-java-api

I want to download jira-rest-java-client-0.2-m1.jar using maven. But I dont know the dependency for that.

I tried the following

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
    <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.2-m1</version>
</dependency>
```

But it is not downloading. When I run `mvn compile` it says

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.444s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu May 02 09:53:19 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/154M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myproject: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.package.myproject:myproject:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
: Failure to find com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client:jar:0.2-m1 in http://repository.codehaus.org was cached in the local repository, resolu
tion will not be reattempted until the update interval of codehaus-release-repo has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Manually I am able to download the jar. But I want to download it using maven. How can I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you can probably just add Atlassian's public repo to your `settings.xml` or your `pom.xml`.

From: https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Atlassian+Maven+Repositories,
the url for the public repo is http://maven.atlassian.com/public

Google searches also suggest this repo URL might work as well: https://repository.atlassian.com/maven2

For example to add to your project's pom.xml,
you would add the following as a child of `<project>`:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>central</id>
    <name>Atlassian Public Repository</name>
    <layout>default</layout>
    <url>http://maven.atlassian.com/public</url>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

(If you already have a repositories section, then you would just add the repository to it).
Here is the documentation for the pom if you would like a little more info: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html

Comment: Thanks. But I don't know how to add. Can you please help me?

Comment: I've added more explicit info above.