# Maven Not downloading some JARs when adding repository for another dependencies

Tags: maven, jira, jira-rest-java-api

I need **jira-rest-java-client:jar:0.2-m1.jar**. So I added the following in my `pom.xml`(Thanks to answer by @kahowell for my [previous question to download that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330346/maven-dependency-for-jira-rest-java-client-0-2-m1-jar))

```
<repository>
    <id>central</id>
    <name>Atlassian Public Repository</name>
    <layout>default</layout>
    <url>http://maven.atlassian.com/public</url>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
```

And dependency is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
    <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.2-m1</version>
</dependency>
```

And it was downloading the JAR but same time it was showing failure that I need to add more JARs and also my program needs some JARs also as one class in this JAR calls other class in other JAR which I needed to add to pom.xml. So I added the following dependencies from maven. And its repository is maven itself.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-apache-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>r06</version>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs.jersey-oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>oauth-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs.jersey-oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>oauth-signature</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>


 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-apache-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Now the problem is, when I add the repository(the one mentioned above) maven downloading the first JAR but not downloading remaining and showing error. When I remove the repository, maven downloads all other JARs except first. I think it is conflicting with repository location but I am not sure.

Can anyone help me how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to add another `repository` to the `Maven Central` as the following:-

```xml
<repositories>
    ...
    <repository>
      <id>Maven Central</id>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
 </repositories>
```

#### EDIT

There are another useful repositories as the following:-

```xml
<repositories>
    ...
    <repository>
      <id>java.net</id>
      <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/public/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>JBoss repository</id>
      <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I hope this may help.